# Compare String with Excel sheetname and pull values from respective sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've an excel file which contains more than 300 different sheets. I want to pull certain values from different sheets by comparing the name of the individual sheets with a defined list of names.

For simplicity below is a sample excel. Sheet1 contains the name of the other sheets and the values should be having the values from respective sheets

[image]

This is how Values are appearing in diffrent sheets:

[image]

The final data will look like -

[image]

It will be really helpful to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value you want from each sheet are in the cell `B3` you can use the `INDIRECT` worksheet function.

Put this formula in `B2` on `Sheet1` and copy it down.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!B3")
```